# Fake FTP server

Tags: c++, unit-testing, ftp, integration-testing

I'm writing a C++ class that performs some operations as an FTP client. I'd like to set up some tests for it so I would need to use a fake FTP server.

I've been searching for one and I think I could write some scripts in Python and use [pyftpdlib](http://code.google.com/p/pyftpdlib/). But I guess there will be some drawbacks as for setting up and tearing down the server after each test.

Any suggestions on how to easily run a fake FTP server for automatic testing in C++ are welcome.

**EDIT:**

I've broadened out my search a little bit and found [MockFtpServer](http://mockftpserver.sourceforge.net/fakeftpserver-features.html), which is exactly what I was looking for, though written in C++ instead of Java.

Comment: What problems did you run into using pyftpdlib?

Comment: @Greg: I didn't try it yet, but I read the documentation on basic usage and think it would not be easy to set up and ter down the server for each test. But I'm just guessing there. I thought I wouldn't be the first SO user facing the problem of writing unit tests for an FTP client, so I could get some advice.

Comment: pyftpdlib's test suite includes a threaded test server which can be started and stopped, returning the control back to the caller immediately:
http://code.google.com/p/pyftpdlib/source/browse/tags/release-0.7.0/test/test_ftpd.py#184

Answer (score 6):

You should design your code for testability, in this case the FTP server is a external resource. Define an adapter between your program and the ftp server. In test you can put a test adapter to fake the FTP response. Now you can also fake different behaviors for the ftp server.

Comment: is this not ignoring that the interface that manages the network packets need to be tested? The user needs to test the FTP adapter, so removing it from the problem removes the problem altogether and leaves the adapter untested.

Comment: If you have written the network protocol, you should test it. But you should test it separately. If you have not written the network protocol you have to trust the people who did. And that they have tested it. Otherwise you should also test all os functions you are using.

Comment: @peer: the thing is that, right now, I'm using a component for the implementation, which I plan to replace for my own code later on. So this is kind of limiting my design at this point. I really need to use a fake FTP server actually listening on a network port for the tests. And I really want to have tests at the time of replacing the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about Unit Testing, then @peer's answer is correct.  You should mock up the FTP connection, because ideally your unit tests are running as part of each build and they shouldn't depend on things that are outside of the client's package.

OTOH, if you're talking about System/Integration Testing, then you should have a working clone of the supported production environment(s), including an FTP server.  I'm not sure why you'd want a 'fake' FTP server for your System/Integration Testing though.  Probably best to go with an FTP server that your clients would actually be using.

Comment: I guess I'm more on the integration testing side. My class is composed by an object providing the FTP client functionality. I could more or less easily make a *seam* so to separately test the logic using the FTP client. Nonetheless, I will eventually need to also test the FTP client logic, thus my need for a fake FTP server. My application should work with *any* FTP server so I would need to test it against a standard compliant server.

Comment: So I don't think you need a fake FTP server for integration testing, you just need some FTP server.  I'm not sure how you would decide which one to use, since there is an ever growing (and already quite large) assortment of FTP servers.  It shouldn't really matter as long it is compliant with the FTP standard as you suggested.